# Clarification on data ingestion sampling in Azure Monitor Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm relying on Application Insights receiving metrics shipped from an azure classic cloud service with different roles for autoscaling. To be more specific, I'm shipping a metric per role.

Would setting the data ingestion sample percentage to 1% prevent autoscaling in some cases? (Assuming metrics are aggregated and shipped every 1 minute from code)

Comment: what's your autoscaling rule?

Comment: @IvanYang my autoscaling rule is to scale up when some metric shipped by telemetryclient is above 70 and down when below 40

Comment: I'm currently not sure, you can keep an eye on this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34166) about alert and sampling.

Comment: @IvanYang thanks for the tip! Will follow and update.

Answer (score 0):

This section is in progress and will be added in ms docs of [sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling).

Please keep an eye on this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34166) for any updates as well as you can comment on that if you have any more issues.